How to declare an instance of TemplateRef in the component code to reuse it multiple times in the markup?
I have several controls where I pass a template. It's the same one for each such occurrence and it appears as a good idea to avoid the code redundancy.
<app-lookup [data]="lookupData[0]">
  <ng-template let-ctx>{{ctx.name}} ...</ng-template>
</app-lookup>
...
<app-lookup [data]="lookupData[99]">
  <ng-template let-ctx>{{ctx.name}} ...</ng-template>
</app-lookup>

I've found a discussion seemingly related to my desire but checking out the linked fiddle doesn't contain any HTML for the component, which makes me suspect that it's less related than originally expected.
I'd like to do something like this in the markup:
<app-lookup *ngFor="index of [1, ..., 99]" [data]="lookupData[index]">
  <ng-container [ngTempalteOutput]="template"></ng-container>
</app-lookup>

...and provide the template from the component code:
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<unknown> = ???;

...but I haven't figured out a way to provide anything useful for ???.

in html: <ng-template #myTemlpate>, in the component @ViewChild('myTemplate'). Read more in the docs

@Shlang Thanks for the reply. My intention is to move the template out from the component's HTML. One alternative is to declare it in the component code (at the question marks, somehow). If that's not feasible, I'd like to declare the template in a separate file/component and then only apply it in the main component here. Is that doable?

"declare it in the component code" - not doable. "in a separate component" - Andrei's answer shows how to do it

you should not put anything in place of ???. @ContentChild decorator will make sure angular populates the field in the class with a corresponding content child.
In some project you can meet helper directives for explicit and clean template marking. In your case it would look like this:
@Directive({selector: '[lookupContent]'})
class LookupContentDirective{
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef) {}
}

....
class AppLookupComponent {
  @ContentChild(LookupContentDirective) content?: LookupContentDirective;
...
// app-lookup.component.html
<div *ngTemplateOutlet="content?.template; context: context"></div>
...
// usage
<app-lookup>
 <li *lookupContent>li will be a template</li>
</app-lookup>


I didn't quite follow. Perhaps the issue I'm facing needs more elaboration. What I'm trying to do is to remove the part <ng-template let-ctx>{{ctx.name}} ...</ng-template> and providing it from the component code. The optimal solution would actually be to pass a reference of a markup to the lookup: <app-lookup templateReference> and keep that reference declared elsewhere. That way, I'd be able to use the lookup in a single line, throwing in one of the templates available. Someone can prepare the template files and make the lookup entirely customizable.

yeah. I think I got you right. user code would look like the very last piece marked with // usage . the rest is only a library one. It will work like this: you write <app-lookup><!-- start of tempalte here--><div *lookupContent>....</div><!-- end of template here --></app-lookup>. considering that lookup-component queries content child by [lookupContent] it will receive the directive instance(which contains the template) and then it can do whatever it wants with the template received. directive is here just for connvinience to mark piece of html as a template
